# Adding custom content to $form

Tags: 7, forms

I have a page that is displaying a form, and I want to add some text to the top of it.

I create my own module for the form, and have it set up like this:

```
function hook_menu(){
  $items['page'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'form_function',
  );
}

function form_function() {
  $form = drupal_get_form('return_form');
  return $form;
}

function return_form(...){
  $form['element'] = ...
    .. ;
}
```

I want to add onto this form with a paragraph or two to go above the form.  I looked at the form api for something i could use from '#type' but I found nothing.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try using hook_form_alter()

For e.g.

```
<?php
function your_module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id == 'your_form_id'){
    //First element in the form.
     $form['element']['#prefix'] = '<div>Your paragraph before the form.</div>'
  }
}
?>
```